# How to read controller list, methods and custom attributes by Xunit test

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit.net

I have huge backend project with a lot of controllers and each controller methods. I want to mark each method with custom attribute, something like this

```
<ApiController>
<Route("[controller]/[action]")>
Public Class OneController
    Inherits ControllerBase

    <MyCustomAttr(State:="OK")>
    <HttpGet>
    Public Function Method1
    ...

    <MyCustomAttr(State:="Has bug")>
    <HttpGet>
    Public Function Method2
    ...

    <MyCustomAttr(State:="Not tested")>
    <HttpGet>
    Public Function Method3
    ...
```

This project supported with related Xunit project. And I want to realize something report like this

```
    OneController
        Method1 : OK
        Method2 : Has bug
        Method3 : Not tested
    TwoController
        Method1 : Not implement
        Method2 : Don't working
```

How I can realize this future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple solution, created for 5 minutes.

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)>
Public Class StateAttribute
    Inherits Attribute
    Public ReadOnly Value
    Public Sub New(value As String)
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub
End Class
```

Than Methods marks by this attribute, and in Xunit project we can see current state.

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Xunit
Imports Xunit.Abstractions
Public Class ProjectState
    Private ReadOnly Log As ITestOutputHelper
    Public Sub New(_Log As ITestOutputHelper)
        Log = _Log
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Sub GetApiState()
        Dim API As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("G:\Projects\BackendAPI.dll")
        Dim Types = API.GetTypes()
        Dim Controllers As List(Of Type) = Types.Where(Function(X) X.Name.Contains("Controller")).ToList
        For i As Integer = 0 To Controllers.Count - 1
            Log.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {Controllers(i).Name.Replace("Controller", "")}")
            Dim Methods As List(Of MethodInfo) = DirectCast(Controllers(i), System.Reflection.TypeInfo).DeclaredMethods.ToList
            For j As Integer = 0 To Methods.Count - 1
                Dim Attributes As List(Of CustomAttributeData) = Methods(j).CustomAttributes.ToList
                For k = 0 To Attributes.Count - 1
                    If Attributes(k).AttributeType.Name = "StateAttribute" Then
                        Log.WriteLine($"        {j + 1}. {Methods(j).Name} : {Attributes(k).ToString.Replace("[BackendAPI.StateAttribute(", "").Replace(")]", "")}")
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

and this is result

[image: Api state]